# link information from various cells in Excel to outlook

Tags: excel, outlook

Is there a way to link information from various cells in Excel to outlook? i have an email template that i write each month,  but data is from Excel

Tried mail merge but cannot find out how to reference specific cells. please advise

Comment: You can put information from Excel cells to outlook email body. Please do a google search. You will get many example. Try to deploy few of them to your sheet. If face any difficulties then comes up with your faulty codes here.